# If $V \subset H$ is dense, then $\Lambda V = \Lambda H$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, exterior-algebra

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $V \subseteq H$ be a dense subspace. The exterior algebra
\begin{equation}
 \oplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \wedge^{n}H
\end{equation}
can be equipped with a canonical inner product that turns it into a pre-Hilbert space, let us write $\Lambda H$ for its Hilbert completion.

> Is it true that $\Lambda V = \Lambda H$?

The following seems like a reasonable proof strategy to me.

We could try to show that
\begin{equation}
 \left( \oplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \wedge^{n}V \right)^{\perp} = \{0 \}.
\end{equation}
This could be done by showing first that
\begin{equation}
 \left( \oplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \wedge^{n}V \right)^{\perp} = \oplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\wedge^{n}V \right)^{\perp},
\end{equation}
where on the right hand side we have that the orthocomplement of $\wedge^{n}V$ is taken in $\wedge^{n}H$. The second step would be to show that, for each $n$, we have that $\wedge^{n}V$ is dense in $\wedge^{n}H$, which would imply that
\begin{equation}
 \wedge^{n}(V)^{\perp} = \{ 0 \}.
\end{equation}

I guess this second step is what I'm not too sure about.